# Do Arnica homeopathic tablets reduce bruising?

Tags: alternative-medicine, natural-remedies, herbalism

My wife recently gave birth and the taking of arnica homeopathic tablets seems to be widely recommended to help with bruising. We've seen it suggested online, several midwives have told her to take them, and even a doctor has mentioned it.

Is there anything to suggest arnica tablets reduce bruising?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) I've made some serious edits; please check you are comfortable with them. You state that the tablets are homeopathic, but you haven't provided any references, so we can't be sure if people are recommending tablets with active ingredients or not. (Not all homeopathic remedies are diluted beyond all possible effect.) I also removed a statement suggesting placebos are not harmful, as that isn't true, and it hasn't been established they are merely placebos. I also removed a motivation question.

Comment: [These Arnica drops](http://www.weleda.com.au/arnica-6x-drops-30ml/w1/i1004259/) are 6X dilution (i.e. 1 part per million), for example.

Comment: The tablets we assume were meant are http://m.boots.com/mt/www.boots.com/en/Boots-Arnica-30c-84-Pillules_845540/ as they are the ones sold by the largest pharmacy chain in the UK. Thanks for the edits @Oddthinking, they look good to me.

Comment: Ah, they are 30C tablets, which (if they are what they say they are on the label) [contain no active ingredient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeopathic_dilutions).

Comment: Yes, which is why I was surprised they were recommended to us by a doctor and some midwives. It's interesting to know that you can buy less dilute tablets. I'd be good to know if anyone knows if they are effective.

Comment: Boots also sell a [6C formulation](http://www.boots.com/en/Nelsons-Arnica-6c-84-Pillules_999088/) which they describe as "Nelsons Arnica 6c is a homeopathic medicinal product without approved therapeutic indications."

Comment: Note from UK parliamentary proceedings http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/health/8527822.stm Boots say that have no evidence they are efficatious

Comment: I don't see how arnica tablets can be called homeopathic, as arnica is actually a proven herbal remedy for bruising. According to homeopathy, it shouldn't work..

Comment: Even after the edits, the question actually asks two questions: one about homeopathic arnica, and, in the last sentence, one about arnica. Arnica has been used a herb to reduce inflammation for centuries but there is no convincing evidence to show that it has a postive effect and is known to be toxic in large doses. Homeopathic arnica, which contains no arnica, is neither anti-inflammatory nor toxic. The 6X tablets referred to above are not sold as being homeopathic. The 6C and 30C tablets sold by Boots are sold as homeopathic and make no claims as to efficacy.

Comment: I think the issue that prompted me to ask this question in the first place is that medical professionals suggested we use arnica. We then went into Boots and asked for arnica and they gave us homeopathic tablets. Perhaps there is a disconnect between what the medical professionals wanted and what we were sold. The question has been edited to focus much more on homeopathic arnica tablets than I intended originally. One of the things I wanted to know was can you get non homeopathic arnica, and is it effective.

Comment: That homeopathy is debunked is shown in the [answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/25216/17867) below. The [wiki link to medical uses of Arnica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnica#Medicinal_uses) provided in the comments to that answer, points to clinical tests indicating that Arnica is beneficial against bruising. This should answer both aspects of the re-formulated question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Has most peer-reviewed research on homeopathy given positive results?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6860/has-most-peer-reviewed-research-on-homeopathy-given-positive-results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything to suggest arnica tablets reduce bruising?

The results seem to suggest **probably not**.  Though, according to one paper, **topical arnica** seemed to perform almost as well as 5% vitamin K cream.

I include four papers I was able to find testing arnica on bruising.  Two of which are homeopathic arnica, the other two are topical arnica.

[**Homeopathic arnica for prevention of pain and bruising: randomized placebo-controlled trial in hand surgery**](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC539394/) (full text linked)

**Abstract**: (emphasis mine)

> Homeopathic arnica is widely believed to control bruising, reduce
>   swelling and promote recovery after local trauma; many patients
>   therefore take it perioperatively. To determine whether this treatment
>   has any effect, we conducted a double-blind, placebo-controlled,
>   randomized trial with three parallel arms. 64 adults undergoing
>   elective surgery for carpal tunnel syndrome were randomized to take
>   three tablets daily of **homeopathic arnica 30C or 6C or placebo** for
>   seven days before surgery and fourteen days after surgery. Primary
>   outcome measures were pain (short form McGill Pain Questionnaire) and
>   bruising (colour separation analysis) at four days after surgery.
>   Secondary outcome measures were swelling (wrist circumference) and use
>   of analgesic medication (patient diary).
>
> 62 patients could be included in the intention-to-treat analysis.
>   **There were no group differences on the primary outcome measures of
>   pain (P=0.79) and bruising (P=0.45) at day four.** Swelling and use of
>   analgesic medication also did not differ between arnica and placebo
>   groups. Adverse events were reported by 2 patients in the arnica 6C
>   group, 3 in the placebo group and 4 in the arnica 30C group.
>
> **The results of this trial do not suggest that homeopathic arnica has
>   an advantage over placebo in reducing postoperative pain, bruising and
>   swelling in patients undergoing elective hand surgery.**

[**Effects of Topical Arnica Gel on Post-Laser Treatment Bruises**](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1046/j.1524-4725.2002.02011.x/abstract?deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=&userIsAuthenticated=false) (full text pay-walled)

Summary:

> **background**. Claims have been made suggesting that topical arnica
>   prevents and speeds the resolution of bruises, yet there are no
>   well-designed placebo-controlled studies to date evaluating topical
>   arnica's effect on bruising.
>
> **objective**. To compare the efficacy of **topical arnica** in the prevention
>   and resolution of laser-induced bruising.
>
> **methods**. Nineteen patients with facial telangiectases were enrolled in
>   this randomized, double-blinded, placebo-controlled study and were
>   divided into pretreatment and posttreatment groups. The pretreatment
>   group applied arnica with vehicle to one side of the face and vehicle
>   alone to the other side of the face twice a day for 2 weeks prior to
>   laser treatment. The posttreatment group followed the same procedure
>   for 2 weeks after laser treatment. On day 0, all patients were treated
>   for facial telangiectases using a 585 nm pulsed dye laser. **Bruising
>   was assessed using a visual analog scale on days 0, 3, 7, 10, 14, and
>   17 by the patient and the physician**. In addition, photographs taken at
>   each of the follow-up visits were later assessed by a second physician
>   using the visual analog scale.
>
> **results**. There was no statistically significant difference between the
>   mean scores of arnica and vehicle (P = 0.496) and the mean scores of
>   arnica and vehicle (P = 0.359) in the pretreatment and posttreatment
>   groups, respectively.
>
> **conclusion**. **No significant difference was found between topical arnica
>   and vehicle in the prevention or resolution of bruising.**

[**Accelerated resolution of laser-induced bruising with topical 20% arnica: a rater-blinded randomized controlled trial**](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2133.2010.09813.x/abstract?deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=&userIsAuthenticated=false) (full text pay-walled)

Summary:

> **Background**  Dermatological procedures can result in disfiguring
>   bruises that resolve slowly.
>
> **Objectives**  To assess the comparative utility of topical formulations
>   in hastening the resolution of skin bruising.
>
> **Methods**  Healthy volunteers, age range 21–65 years, were enrolled for
>   this double (patient and rater) blinded randomized controlled trial.
>   For each subject, four standard bruises of 7 mm diameter each were
>   created on the bilateral upper inner arms, 5 cm apart, two per arm,
>   using a 595-nm pulsed-dye laser (Vbeam; Candela Corp., Wayland, MA,
>   U.S.A.). Randomization was used to assign **one topical agent (5%
>   vitamin K, 1% vitamin K and 0·3% retinol, 20% arnica, or white
>   petrolatum) to exactly one bruise per subject**, which was then treated
>   under occlusion twice a day for 2 weeks. A dermatologist not involved
>   with subject assignment rated bruises [visual analogue scale, 0
>   (least)–10 (most)] in standardized photographs immediately after
>   bruise creation and at week 2.
>
> **Results**  There was significant difference in the change in the rater
>   bruising score associated with the four treatments (anova, P = 0·016).
>   Pairwise comparisons indicated that the mean improvement associated
>   with 20% arnica was greater than with white petrolatum (P = 0·003),
>   and the improvement with arnica was greater than with the mixture of
>   1% vitamin K and 0·3% retinol (P = 0·01). **Improvement with arnica was
>   not greater than with 5% vitamin K cream, however**.
>
> Conclusions  **Topical 20% arnica ointment may be able to reduce
>   bruising more effectively than placebo and more effectively than
>   low-concentration vitamin K formulations, such as 1% vitamin K with
>   0·3% retinol**.

**[Effect of Homeopathic Arnica montana on Bruising in Face-lifts
Results of a Randomized, Double-blind, Placebo-Controlled Clinical Trial](https://archfaci.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=480929)** (full text linked)

Summary:

> **Objectives**  To design a model for performing reproducible, objective
>   analyses of skin color changes and to apply this model to evaluate the
>   efficacy of **homeopathic Arnica montana** as an antiecchymotic agent when
>   taken perioperatively.
>
> **Methods**  Twenty-nine patients undergoing rhytidectomy at a tertiary
>   care center were treated perioperatively with either homeopathic A
>   montana or placebo in a double-blind fashion. Postoperative
>   photographs were analyzed using a novel computer model for color
>   changes, and subjective assessments of postoperative ecchymosis were
>   obtained.
>
> **Results**  **No subjective differences were noted between the treatment
>   group and the control group, either by the patients or by the
>   professional staff. No objective difference in the degree of color
>   change was found. Patients receiving homeopathic A montana were found
>   to have a smaller area of ecchymosis on postoperative days 1, 5, 7,
>   and 10. These differences were statistically significant (P<.05) only
>   on postoperative days 1 (P<.005) and 7 (P<.001).**
>
> **Conclusions**  This computer model provides an efficient, objective, and
>   reproducible means with which to assess perioperative color changes,
>   both in terms of area and degree. Patients taking perioperative
>   homeopathic A montana exhibited less ecchymosis, and that difference
>   was statistically significant (P<.05) on 2 of the 4 postoperative data
>   points evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

[According to the NHS,](http://www.nhs.uk/conditions/homeopathy/Pages/Introduction.aspx)

> A 2010 House of Commons Science and Technology Committee report on homeopathy said that homeopathic remedies perform no better than placebos, and that the principles on which homeopathy is based are "scientifically implausible". This is also the view of the Chief Medical Officer, Professor Dame Sally Davies.

This means that homeopathy has been shown to be no different from a [placebo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placebo) (i.e. a negative control treatment). This implies that the only effects generated by the homeopathic "treatment" are due to the placebo, and not the "treatment" itself.

As mentioned in the comments, from a chemical viewpoint, any dilution above 12C contains such a low dilution that no molecules of the original chemical remain in the supposed "medicine", and therefore there is no scientific basis for homeopathy being a plausible remedy.

IMO, the best counter to any homeopath is that tap water is an unimaginably strong homeopathic remedy of [literally everything possible](http://www.consumeraffairs.com/news/homeopathic-remedies-all-the-benefits-of-tap-water-at-a-million-times-the-price-102413.html), [including dinosaurs](http://www.quackometer.net/blog/2011/12/your-perfect-homeopathy-kit-for-christmas.html).

Comment: You fail to show that arnica is actually a homeopathic medicine. In fact, it isn't. It's a herbal medicine and it actually works... http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnica#Medicinal_uses

Comment: @EbenezerSklivvze Seriously?? OP's question stated "homeopathic" clearly.

Comment: @MarchHo He did, but who says the OP is right? He's asking about a specific chemical, not if homeopathic treatments in general are effective.

Comment: @SpellingD All homeopathic "remedies" (with the exception of those with lower dilution levels than 12C) are chemically identical, so it makes no sense to distinguish between them. Since OP specified a 30C "remedy", it is reasonable to condemn it in the exact same way for any other homeopathic "remedy".

Comment: The OP just gave an example, he's not asking about 30C in particular in the question. Please answer *specifically* and not *generically*. We already have other more general "homeopathy" questions, the reason this was not closed as a dupe is to allow a specific answer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZO9J7dDLU4 Not strictly an answer to this specific question but it does highlight a big failing in homoeopathy in general, plus you can repeat the experiment yourself if you have the patience.  And then you can drink the real vodka when boredom with the whole project sets in!